# Need to find the sum of the values ​of the second nesting

Tags: php, arrays, laravel-5, collections

i have a
`$collection->content[0...n]->video[0]->length` I try something like that:

```
<span>
@foreach($collection->content as $video)
   {{$video->videos[0]->length}}
@endforeach
</span>
```

and received `<span>268864 254004 200992 224770 234708 266217 305552</span>`
but i need sum of these numbers

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Nothing that work)

Comment: Please add a full code sample of what you have, including the $collection, this would help us help you.